# ¿Cómo insertar información en SQLite desde una base de datos en un servidor (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, android, sqlite

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android Studio y tengo dos bases de datos, la primera está en SQLite y la segunda en un servidor (MySQL).

Lo que quiero es hacer un "insert" de datos en mi SQLite desde el servidor, pero no necesito todas las columnas.

Me refiero a que, por ejemplo, en la base de datos en SQLite tengo los siguientes campos:

1. Id
2. Name
3. City

y en el servidor tengo los siguientes:

1. Id
2. Name
3. City
4. Telephone
5. Age

Solo necesito insertar en SQLite los campos Id-Name-City.

El propósito es que cuando el usuario presione un botón, la base de datos en el servidor haga una inserción en la base de datos de SQLite, solo con los campos que dije antes.

Mi botón:

```
btnInicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //Añadir aqui la funcionalidad del boton necesaria para hacer la insercción de datos desde el servidor a SQLite

    //Si la informacion ha sido añadida correctamente...
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Los datos han sido añadidos correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   //Si no...

   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error en la insercción de datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}});
```

¿Como podría hacerlo?

Comment: La mejor forma de gestionar la BBDD es usando un ORM como por ejemplo SugarORM

Comment: Podría ser una buena opción si estuviera empezando el proyecto, pero ya lleva un tiempo y las bases de datos ya están creadas, supongo que sería demasiado trabajoso cambiarlo todo ahora...

Comment: mira bien como funciona y veras que no realiza cambios en BBDD sin quieres y te ayuda a gestionar las operaciones del CRUD

Comment: Pero con eso, podría hacer un "insert" o "update" de datos desde la base de datos que tengo en el servidor, a la base de datos en android?

Comment: Esa es para el móvil para el servidor podrías tener otro. Eso depende siempre de donde apuntes,

Comment: Ya, pero es que lo que yo quiero es pasar datos desde una base de datos en un servidor, a una base de datos en Android...

Comment: Deberias hacer una llamada desde la app android al servidor que tengas alojada la BBDD MySQL

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de código para saber como sería?

Comment: Esto no es algo nuevo te aconsejo que googlees un poco no te costara dar con mas de una solución.